# add dimension to an xarray DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I need to add a dimension to a `DataArray`, filling the values across the new dimension. Here's the original array.

```
a_size = 10
a_coords = np.linspace(0, 1, a_size)

b_size = 5
b_coords = np.linspace(0, 1, b_size)

# original 1-dimensional array
x = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.random(a_size),
    coords=[('a', a coords)])
```

I guess I could create an empty DataArray with the new dimension and copy the existing data in.

```
y = xr.DataArray(
    np.empty((b_size, a_size),
    coords=([('b', b_coords), ('a', a_coords)])
y[:] = x
```

A better idea might be to be to use `concat`. It took me a while to figure out how to specify both the dims and the coords for the concat dimension, and none of these options seem great. Is there something I'm missing that can makes this version cleaner?

```
# specify the dimension name, then set the coordinates
y = xr.concat([x for _ in b_coords], 'b')
y['b'] = b_coords

# specify the coordinates, then rename the dimension
y = xr.concat([x for _ in b_coords], b_coords)
y.rename({'concat_dim': 'b'})

# use a DataArray as the concat dimension
y = xr.concat(
    [x for _ in b_coords],
    xr.DataArray(b_coords, name='b', dims=['b']))
```

Still, is there a better way to do this than either of the two above options?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `DA` is your data array with length `DimLen`, you can now use `expand_dims`:

```
DA.expand_dims({'NewDim':DimLen})
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way that math is applied over new dimensions I like to multiply in order to add new dimensions.

```
identityb = xr.DataArray(np.ones_like(b_coords), coords=[('b', b_coords)])
y = x * identityb
```

Comment: Quick solution although it leads to lose the available attributes in x

Answer (score 4):

Using `.assign_coords` method will do it. However you can't assign coordinates to a non-existant dimension, the way to do as a one liner is:

```py
y = x.expand_dims({b_coords.name: b_size}).assign_coords({b_coords.name: b_coords})
```

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the syntax of the question:

```
y = x.expand_dims({"b": b_coords})
```